# Getting "Insufficient permissions to list objects" error with S3 bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I setup a bucket policy to allow two external users `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/user1` and `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/user2` to access everything under a particular path in our S3 bucket - `s3:my-bucket-name/path/`. But the user is getting the following error when trying to access the path on AWS console:

> **Insufficient permissions to list objects**
> After you or your AWS administrator have updated your permissions to allow the s3:ListBucket action, refresh the page. Learn more about identity and access management in Amazon S3.

Here's the policy document. What am I missing here?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "allowAccessToBucketPath",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/user1",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/user2"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/path/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/path"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/user1",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/user2"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "path/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check if you have any ACLs enabled for your bucket. In your bucket settings, check if Object Ownership is set to "ACLs enabled", in which case I would suggest you change it to "ACLs disabled".

If that doesn't work, I would suggest using the IAM Access Analyzer to help troubleshoot -- if the Access Analyzer says that your policy does in fact allow the access you want, then that would indicate that this policy is correctly defined, and you have other configurations on your bucket preventing the access.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-analyzer.html

Comment: I used the Access Analyzer but it didn't provide much useful information - it shows both users have `s3:ListBucket` among a bunch of other Read/Write/List access.
As I'm reading more I'm starting to think the error could be caused by the user was trying to access via the AWS Console. 

In this doc (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-with-s3-actions.html) it mentioned:
If a user wants to use the AWS Management Console to view buckets and the contents of any of those buckets, the user must have the `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` and `s3:GetBucketLocation` permissions.